# How to get the value of radius of a circle

Tags: c++, opencv, gaussian, hough-transform, iris-recognition

For the Hough circle transformation, when I had detected the circle, how can I get the value of the circle's radius and the center point? I am doing an iris recognition system.

```
CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(grayscaleImg,
                     storage,
                     CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
                     2,
                     grayscaleImg->height/4,
                     200,
                 100 );

for (i = 0; i < circles->total; i++) 
{
     float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem( circles, i );
     cvCircle( capturedImg, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), 
        3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
     cvCircle( capturedImg, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), 
         cvRound(p[2]), CV_RGB(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
}
```

Comment: What is `cvRound`, `cvCircle` ? What semantically does `cvGetSeqElem` return ?

Comment: sorry, i missed up somethings, it's used to find circle and its center point in an image

Comment: Your code already operates with center coordinates and radius.

Comment: I don't get it. You are drawing circles here with center points and radius. And you can't find them?

Comment: Yes, I get it but i want to show the value of radius that have been found on the screen.                                                For example, 'the circle has 5mm radius at point(5.0,4.0)!!! 'on the screen.

Comment: before that, i am using cvPutText but unable to convert the cvpoint to char. Therefore, before that, is it I need to do any conversion?

Comment: Dude, organize your thought and rewrite your question. It will help you and us to find an answer.

Comment: Use itoa to convert integer to string. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: Yes, i want to convert the integer to string. Because the value I get in cvRound is in data type of integer however, I need to convert it to string for using in cvPutText. Thx Matthew.

Answer (score 2):

Center point: `cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1]))`

Radius      : `cvRound(p[2])`